# Can you specify an executable as the application's other than CFBundleExecutable?

Tags: macos, plist, info.plist

I have a makeshit dotapp bundle which specifies a bash script as the CFBundleExecutable value. OS X launches this application, but the bash script is invoking a separate executable which then pops up a second icon on the dock.

I've been through the documentation, there don't seem to be any other keys that can be used to specify that the executable that launches is different than the executable that the application runs as.

Is there another approach to this that would make it work properly?